restar dias a una fecha de una consulta Mysql
hola a todos espero esten bien
tengo en una base de datos una serie de registros en la cual existe una fecha y quiero restarle a esa fecha seleccionada 3 dias las fechas estan en formato Y-m-d (ejemplo: 2024-08-20)
SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE fechafinal 

a esa fechafinal es la que quiero restarle -3 días para luego comprarla con la actual para que así me de una alerta con 3 días de anticipación..
Estara bien hacerlo asi..
$fechaactual=date("Y-m-d");
$fechaactualcalculada= date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fechaactual."+ 3 days")); 
        $querytermcont = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE fechafinal ='$fechaactualcalculada'");
         $hayy = $result->num_rows;
         //echo "hay ".$hayy;
    while ($valorestermcont = mysqli_fetch_array($querytermcont)){ 
     echo "<div class='alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'><div class='spinner-grow' role='status'>
  <span class='visually-hidden'></span>
</div>
  <strong>NOTA:</strong> Existen <b>$hayy</b> Documentos por vencer en 3 dias, <a  rel='pop-up2p' href='https://pagina.com/verdocumentos.php'>  Ir </a>  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
  <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
</button></div>"; 
}


Creo que se entiende mejor al revés. A la fecha actual CURDATE() le sumas +3 días, para que devuelva las fechas de la tabla que tienen exactamente 3 días más.

Pero cual es el problema???

agregue al final de mi consulta parte del código que llevo, a ver si estará bien así??

Y no se.. funciona o no?

le puse asi para hacer pruebas $fechaactual="2024-08-17"; para ver si aparecen asi los registros con las fechas del dia 20 (17+3=20) de hoy y nada no me resulta.. :(

Tus cadenas son exactamente iguales?? en la db y la que estas construyendo?? con los ceros y todo???

Puedes usar un intervalo temporal: WHERE fechafinal +interval 3 day = current_date.

Según se ve en el código, lo que interesa es contar el total de filas cuya fechafinal será dentro de tres días.
Lo puedes lograr con esta consulta:
SELECT 
  COUNT(`fechafinal`) AS `total`
FROM `mitabla`
WHERE `fechafinal` = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 3 DAY)
GROUP BY `fechafinal`;

En cuanto al código PHP, no necesitas un while ni num_rows para esto. Veamos:
$sql="SELECT 
      COUNT(`fechafinal`) AS `total`
    FROM `mitabla`
    WHERE `fechafinal` = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 3 DAY)
    GROUP BY `fechafinal`";
$row=$mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
$hayy=$row['total'];
echo "<div class='alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'><div class='spinner-grow' role='status'>
  <span class='visually-hidden'></span>
</div>
  <strong>NOTA:</strong> Existen <b>$hayy</b> Documentos por vencer en 3 dias, <a  rel='pop-up2p' href='https://pagina.com/verdocumentos.php'>  Ir </a>  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
  <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
</button></div>"; 

Con esto deberías ver el total de filas que vencen dentro de tres días.
Aquí te dejo un fiddle, donde muestra a día de hoy un total de tres registros, que son los que expiran el próxima día 24.
CREATE TABLE `mitabla` (`fechafinal` DATE);

INSERT INTO `mitabla` VALUES ('2024-08-21'),('2024-08-24'),('2024-08-24'),('2024-08-24'),('2024-08-25'),('2024-08-25'),('2024-08-26'),('2024-08-26');


Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT 
  `fechafinal`,
  COUNT(`fechafinal`) AS `total`
FROM `mitabla`
WHERE `fechafinal` = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 3 DAY)
GROUP BY `fechafinal`;




fechafinal
total




2024-08-24
3



fiddle

Según la pregunta y el código que has puesto, necesitas que a partir del día de HOY, calcular en 3 días los documentos que están por vencer.
Esto se puede hacer de 2 formas.
Desde la base de datos:
SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE fechafinal=DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 3 DAY)

Usando PHP.
Pareciera mejor hacer esto desde la base de datos, tal como la forma anterior; sin embargo, esta otra versión podrías ser útil para otras cosas, por ejemplo, si la fecha de vencimiento cae fin de semana o días no laborables y trasladarlos a otro día.
$dto = new DateTime(); // <-- HOY
$dto->modify('+3 day');
$nueva_fecha = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
$querytermcont = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM mitabla WHERE fechafinal='$nueva_fecha'");
// ...

